# inno-setup update file in all subdirectories where it exists

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to create an installer that will update a single csv file, that exists in various locations depending on which of our applications a user has installed. 
Our applications install inside a folder with our Company Name in Program Files.

So, Company > App1, Company > App2, Company > App3, etc. When the csv file exists, it is directly inside the App folder.

I've tried:

```
[Files]
Source: "file.csv"; DestDir: "{pf}\Company\*";
```

With various flags and functions to no avail

```
flag: onlyifdestfileexists
```

Skips everything because it doesn't exist

```
Check: FileExists('file.csv')
```

Does nothing at all

```
Check: FileExistsWildcard('file.csv')
```

Which calls a function using FindFirst() tries to create a new directory called * to install the file in, rather than overwriting the file in the directory where it was found, as does

```
[Files]
Source: "file.csv"; DestDir: "{pf}\Company\"; Check: FileExistsWildcard('*\file.csv')
```

The problem seems to have to do with the wildcard * not doing anything when used with DestDir. Instead of searching through all subfolders, it just looks for a subfolder named "*". The recursesubdirs flag of course works for iterating over subdirectories for Source, but there is no equivalent for DestDir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards like that are not supported in `DestDir`.

If you know the names of all possible subdirectories up front (which presumably is the case as these are your own applications) then the simplest way to do this is to include multiple `[Files]` entries, one for each possible application.  You can then use the `onlyifdestfileexists` flag.  Note that when using the same `Source` path on multiple entries, only one copy of the file will be stored inside the installer, so it won't bloat the size.

---

If your applications support being installed into different locations (as most do) then you'll need to modify this slightly; instead of hard-coding the `DestDir` you'll need to have each entry look something like this:

```
Source: file.csv; DestDir: {code:FindAppPath|App1}; Flags: onlyifdestfileexists
```

with corresponding `[Code]` function:

```
function FindAppPath(AppName: String): String;
```

In this function, use `RegQueryStringValue` or other methods to look up the currently installed location of the application being searched for (via `AppName`, which can either be an arbitrary string of your choosing or could be part of the registry path being looked up; alternately you could write separate functions for each application if that's easier).  If a given application is not installed, then return `''`, which will then skip installing the file due to the `onlyifdestfileexists` flag.  Note that you will still need one entry per application, so you will need to know in advance the maximum number of possibly installed applications.

(An alternate means of skipping installation if you didn't wish to use this flag is to define a `Check` function eg. `Check: IsAppInstalled('App1')` or `Check: IsApp1Installed`.)

---

If you don't know (or don't want to rely on knowing) the maximum possible number of installed applications up front, then the only solution is to fall back to pure `[Code]`.  You will need to have a single `[Files]` entry like so:

```
Source: file.csv; DestDir: {tmp}; AfterInstall: CopyToApplications
```

And then implement the `CopyToApplications` procedure to locate the paths to all the possible installations (again, probably via `RegQueryStringValue`) and then for each one:

```
FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\file.csv'), AddBackslash(PathToApp) + 'file.csv');
```

You may also want to look at the CodeDlg example script and use `CreateOutputProgressPage` to provide feedback to the user while this process is going on, although it may not be necessarily if the file size is small enough.

---

Note that in all cases you probably want to disable uninstallation support (since each app's own individual uninstaller will take care of it); make sure you have `Uninstallable=no` in the `[Setup]` section.

Comment: Thanks. Using separate entries in [Files] sections was the conclusion I came to. I had hoped just as a workaround until I discovered some "magic" for iterating through destination subfolders. I used the onlyifdestfileexists flag, and set it for no uninstaller, but don't have anything setup in case user changes install location. I'll definitely go back and do that, thanks for the tips on implementing that.